# how to load data source for connection in VS2012 for web

Tags: visual-studio-2012, datasource, devart, dotconnect

Hi I'm using VS2012 for web express as my tool. I want to use dotconnect postgreSQL for my MVC project. So I tried to add connection to my database explorer. But only Microsoft SQL servers appear in data source list. How can I load different kinds of data source to the list?

Comment: We have reproduced the issue. We will investigate it and post here about the results as soon as possible.

Comment: dotConnect for PostgreSQL has some restrictions for Visual Studio Express editions (except Microsoft Web Developer Express 2008 and 2010). Thus advanced Visual Studio integration (DDEX) for dotConnect for PostgreSQL is not available in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web.